# Pinax build_static error

Tags: static, media, pinax

Following the Pinax documentation (development version), I set up an app in a virtual environment.  Then, I ran "python manage.py build_static" inside my project directory.  That triggered an error:

Unknown command: 'build_static'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

you must to activate the virtual environment first

```
Ex: $ source ../pinax-env/bin/activate
```

[see here](http://pinaxproject.com/docs/0.7/install/)